# Show a block of locations based off proximity search

Tags: views, location

I've created a map, using Geofield, Leaflet and proximity search.  This works great.  I also wanted to add a block view on the same page that shows an unformatted list based off the proximity search.  Image attached for clarity.

[image]

The block view on the right of the display is what I want filtered to show the exact same output as the main map.  I've tried every combination of contextual filters on the block view, just can't seem to make it work.  Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: You could just duplicate your map view and change the view plugin to whatever suits you (e.g. unformatted list...).

Comment: Thanks Volker, I tried that from that start.  Duplicate the view, change the format to a list, but the results are never correct.  If I add an attachment to the page (which I don't want to do) it filters perfectly.  Do I need to add a contextual filter to the block?

Comment: An attachment can inherit the filters, so that may be the reason for that it's working. I think, the problem is that the map is updated dynamically which is not easy to apply to a block in that case. Can't help any further here right now... sorry.